# Finding an element in a dynamic string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table , in some of `<td>` , I have an anchor tag with values . I have to find the value of this by looping.
Here is what I am trying:

```
$(tr).find('td').each(function() {

  var cells = $(this).html();
  var check = $(cells).find("a");
}
```

I am getting an error at :
`var check = $(cells).find("a");`
 because
the first `<td>` value is "SomeText"
and second `<td>` value is

Edit:

```
 "<input id="1"> <a > 188</a></input>"
```

I am trying to extract the output as 188

Comment: Why not do `$(tr).find("td a")`?

Comment: `<input id="1" <a > 188</a><input` is invalid `html`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of the HTML. If the TD's "value" is `"<input id="1" <a > 188</a><input"` then you've got invalid html. Why are both inputs missing a closing `>`?

Comment: the problem is that you are using $ on an invalid selector, therefore the jquery results in an empty set of elements, which of course wont have an `a` tag in them

Comment: all you need is `var check = $(this).find("a");`

Comment: you can use eq() like this $("tr > td").eq(4).find("a") or like this $("tr > td:nth-child(2) a")

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table > tbody  > tr > td > a').each(function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```